# Ember.binding.or in Ember-1.9.1

Tags: ember.js

I am upgrading Ember from 0.9.8 to 1.9.1

I find a line of code, where binding happens based on a logical OR condition

```
dirtyBinding: Ember.Binding.or('oController.isDirty', 'oController.isDirty')
```

How do I get this done in `ember 1.9.1` as `Ember.Binding.or` , `Ember.Binding.and` seem to have deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dirtyBinding: Ember.computed.or('oController.isDirty', 'oController.isDirty')
```

Comment: You should accept your answer so it doesn’t show as unanswered.